# Storage Spaces on Windows Server 2016: Virtual disk operational status suboptimal

Tags: windows-server-2016

What does it mean?
I can't find any documentation anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use [Optimize-Volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848675(v=wps.630).aspx) against VMStorage virtual disk? I also was not able to find description for all possible HealthStatus values in general and for Suboptimal in particular. If no parameters specified Optimize-Volume will perform default action based on disk type:

- **HDD, Fixed VHD, Storage Space** -Analyze -Defrag.
- **Tiered Storage Space** -TierOptimize.
- **SSD with TRIM support** -Retrim.
- **Storage Space (Thinly provisioned), SAN Virtual Disk (Thinly provisioned), Dynamic VHD, Differencing VHD** -Analyze -SlabConsolidate -Retrim.
- **SSD without TRIM support, Removable FAT, Unknown** - No operation.

You may also want to look at this [TechNet Forums thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e08520a8-7994-465c-8646-61c4edaed62e/how-to-rebalance-a-cluster-virtual-disk-in-windows-server-2016?forum=winserverClustering) which mentions the same status.

Answer (score 3):

I have not managed to find an exact description of the operational status section also. But I would recommend to check your physical drives participating in that logical disk since it seems like an individual drive failure. I just made some analogies about logical disks on a hardware RAID which actually guided me to this.

Comment: Yea we had a failure.
Optimize-Volume after it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell command helped me:

```
Get-StoragePool -FriendlyName "s2d*" | Optimize-StoragePool
```